# Вывести на страничке alert-окно с вычисленным значением

Tags: javascript

```js
function showChange() {
  var select = document.getElementById("x");
  var value = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
  alert(value);
}

function measureDistance() {
  var select = document.getElementById("x");
  var valueX = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
  select = document.getElementById("y");
  var valueY = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
  var result = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(valueY, 2) + Math.Pow(valueX, 2))
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <FORM name="form">
    <select id="x" name="x" onChange="showChange()">
      <option name="0"> 0</option>
      <option name="1"> 1</option>
      <option name="2"> 2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="y" name="y" onChange="measureDistance()">
      <option name="0"> 0</option>
      <option name="1"> 1</option>
      <option name="2"> 2</option>
    </select>
  </FORM>
</body>
```

Не понимаю, почему `showChange()` работает, а `measureDistance ()`-- нет.
Код должен выполнять простую задачку расчёта по координатам (с использованием `select`) расстояния до точки. в Google Chrome не работает.

Comment: `Math.sqrt`, `Math.pow`

Comment: Использую при вычислении, но этого, видимо, недостаточно.

Comment: Будьте внимательнее.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что эти функции отдельно надо использовать?

Comment: Я сделал Вам работающий пример. Нажмите на кнопку "Выполнить код". Выберите значение во втором селекте. Прочитайте сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Ага, спасибо, понял!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.sqrt`, `Math.pow`

```js
function showChange() {
  var select = document.getElementById("x");
  var value = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
  alert(value);
}

function measureDistance() {
  var select = document.getElementById("x");
  var valueX = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
  select = document.getElementById("y");
  var valueY = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
  var result = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(valueY, 2) + Math.pow(valueX, 2))
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
  <FORM name="form">
    <select id="x" name="x" onChange="showChange()">
      <option name="0"> 0</option>
      <option name="1"> 1</option>
      <option name="2"> 2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="y" name="y" onChange="measureDistance()">
      <option name="0"> 0</option>
      <option name="1"> 1</option>
      <option name="2"> 2</option>
    </select>
  </FORM>
```